# How check if Excel worksheet is protected?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to check if Excel worksheet is protected or not. I know that I can check `.protectcontents`, but what if worksheet is protected like this:

```
activesheet.protect contents:=false
```

`.protectcontents` returns `false` but shapes are locked.
Please help.

Comment: http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=239

Comment: I just wrote that .protectcontents isn't solution for me. please read my post carefully

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The three protection properties of a worksheet are the following:

- `Sheets(1).ProtectContents`
- `Sheets(1).ProtectDrawingObjects`
- `Sheets(1).ProtectScenarios`

You can check whether both 3 are `False`. If this is the case, it is not protected.

`.ProtectionMode` says whether "User-Interface-only" protection is turned on. You may add it to the function, if you need it. [MSDN - ProtectionMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-protectionmode-property-excel)